# For loop supposed to print 4 rows. it only prints one

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a list called **deck**, which has 104 elements. I want to create a for loop, that displays images on a canvas in a simple GUI (that can only be run on CodeSkulptor, the link to my program's here:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_kgywoL4h56_1.py )

The loop only prints the first row, I think the way I update coordinates of the centre of the image is what's wrong with my code.

```
    if center_d[0] >= WIDTH:
        center_s[1] += height
        center_d[1] += height
```

The entire loop's below and if you need more context, visit the link to my program, that i provided above. Thanks!

```
def draw(canvas):
    global deck, cards, WIDTH, HEIGHT
    width = 70
    height = 106
    center_s = [41, 59]
    center_d = [41, 59]
    for card in deck:
        canvas.draw_image(deck_img, center_s, (width, height), center_d, (width, height))
        center_s[0] += 70
        center_d[0] += 70
        if center_d[0] >= WIDTH:
            center_s[1] += height
            center_d[1] += height
```

Comment: `center_s[1] += height` at the bottom is repeated twice.. I think you really did not want that

Comment: thanks, I've fixed it, still the same result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about your `center_s[0]` and `center_s[0]` coordinates. They are growing constantly.
You need to set them to zero, e.g like this:

```
if center_d[0] >= WIDTH:
    center_s[0] = 41
    center_d[0] = 41
    center_s[1] += height
    center_d[1] += height
```